# Using type alias with templates circular dependency

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

The commented line would not work, because MyArray needs MyValue but MyValue needs MyArray (this is a simplified sample). I could use a struct but I feel like there probably is a better way. Inheriting class doesn't work because I need constructors and operators.

```
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

struct MyValue;

using MyArray = std::vector<MyValue>;
// using MyValue = std::variant<int, MyArray>;

struct MyValue {
    std::variant<int, MyArray> v;
};

int main() {}
```

Comment: do you really need a `MyValue` that may contain a `MyArray` that consists of `MyValue`s that may contain a `MyArray` that consists of `MyValue`s ...etc...? maybe some kind of tree structure can help

Comment: I feel like it's simpler than implementing a tree myself. The real version try to represent a JSON structure.

Comment: Could you use a template instead of a `variant`?

Comment: @JonathanMee what do you mean ?

Comment: Using perhaps `template <T> struct MyValue { variant<int, T> v; };`